# java FX - greying out Datepicker days in calendar

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently working on logic in my car rental application which validates if car is already booked for particular time, if yes it does not allow reservation.

I am searching through all list of rents positions, if I want to reserve car (validating by car VIN number) at the same date when car is already rented I am looking for logic which does not allow reservation (those days in DatePicker will be greyed out

Here is my part of code, what should I add to have it implemented

```
    for (CarFx lcs : carFxList) {         // list of cars that are rented at this moment

        if (lcs.getVin().equals(vinTextField.getText())) {   // I am checking if car is already reserved by someone comparing VIN number (VIN number of car rented and VIN car I want to make a new reservation)

            lcs.getDays();  //return number of days for which car is booked
            .........
```

missing part of code which grey out from DatePicker days when car is booked (from reservation day until reservation day + getDays()

```
        }

        else {

            this.releaseDatePicker.valueProperty()
                    .bindBidirectional(this.carModel.getCarFxObjectProperty().releaseDateProperty()); // here I can choose whatever the date I want

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How should I implement code to meet this criteria, for example I found something similar but not quite the same:

Comment: public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
             super.updateItem(date, empty);
             LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

             setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(today) < 0 );

         }

Comment: this code above allows me to deactivate days in the past but I need logic to deactivate some specific days that I can get by searching through already rented positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution would be to use the code in your comment and call updateItem on each date from the current date `LocalDate.now()` to `LocalDate.plusDays(lcs.getDays())` with the date as the first argument and the second argument `empty`as "false".

Comment: You need to loop from i=0 to i=lcs.getDays() and call updateItem(updateItem(LocalDate.now.plusDays(i), false)

Comment: maybe can I send you link to my git repo to check my program? there is still something not correct..

Comment: maybe I can send you print screen using umgur?

Comment: for me is strange because all brackets are closed :)

Comment: Your loop is wrong there needs to be less than sign in the i=lcs.getdays and your function needs to be defined outside of the loop and in the loop you call the function in the loop

Comment: can you help me with line 129?

Comment: I think this is the missing part:

Comment: setDisable(empty || date == getReleaseDate);

Comment: my program still is not working, there must be some different issue ;/

Comment: Although I have no error program is not running as expected

Comment: @TomekMłynarski If the problem is still related to this question you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53943245/edit) to include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. If this question is solved please feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and, if you feel this answer solved the problem in your question, consider accepting this answer.